# MySQL Select: WHERE (time now) = BETWEEN tablevalue AND tablevalue

Tags: mysql, select, time, where-clause

I'm looking for a way to select the row in which the current time is between two set values in the row. I've set up a table with 3 columns, 2 of them hold a timestamp (HH:MM:SS), the other one a string. Is there a way I can get the string corresponding to the current time?
To put it in a more abstract way:

SELECT String FROM TableName WHERE (Current Time) BETWEEN (Lower Limit Time Value) AND (Upper Limit Time Value);

[image]

So basically, based on the current time, my script should output the correct string.

How do I go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: Which type are the `lower_limit` and `upper_limit`?

Comment: Does your night span over two days? `BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '05:00:00'` would probably not return what you await.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `MySQL`, timestamp is quite a confusing word.

If they are `lowerlimit` and `upperlimit` are `TIME` columns from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`:

```
SELECT  String
FROM    TableName
WHERE   CURTIME() BETWEEN lowerlimit AND upperlimit
        OR CURTIME() BETWEEN SUBTIME(upperlimit, '24:00:00') AND lowerlimit
        OR SUBTIME(CURTIME(), '24:00:00') BETWEEN SUBTIME(upperlimit, '24:00:00') AND lowerlimit
```

This will handle midnight transitions correctly.

Comment: Made the same mistake at first. NOW() contains date part as well. CURTIME() should be used. Downvote not from me.

Comment: ?? Not sure what you're asking about. Anyway now your answer fits the question much better than others.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work when I remove the OR part, if I don't leave it out everything after the 'lowerlimit' is returned. 

Also, I have no midnight transitions from the 'lower' to 'upper' limit. :] You should know that I know very, very little about MySQL, would you mind explaining the last part?

Comment: @Chris: `BETWEEN` is directed, so `2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1` is `true` but `2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1` is `false`. In `MySQL`, time can be negative so if you have a midnight transition (from `22:00` to `01:00`) it will convert it into `BETWEEN '-02:00' AND '01:00'`

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT string_col
FROM your_table
WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN lower_limit_col AND upper_limit_col
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you did is pretty much it:

```
SELECT String FROM TableName WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN (Lower Limit Time Value) AND (Upper Limit Time Value);
```

Comment: Are the brackets also correct in MySQL? I'm not familiar with the syntax and I'm currently using `Something` (normal 'quotes' don't seem to work) in my queries via PHP.

Comment: No. Backticks ( ` ) are correct way to delimit non standard column names. i.e.

Answer (score 2):

the type of the two columns should be time (and not timestamp). Then, the answer is in your question :

```
select string from tablename where curtime() between lowerlimit and upperlimit
```

Just make sure that the night doesnt go from 22:00:00 to 06:00:00 though, or it won't work. But you might introduce two intervals for the might : one from 22:00:00 to 24:00:00, and another one from 00:00:00 to 06:00:00.

Comment: Ah, I don't have those transitions fortunately, thanks for the heads up though!