# Mysql Query for daily hits

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm monitoring hits on a website with timestamps. How do I get the hits for a whole day in MySQL? The result should look like: today => 10 hits. The hits are stored as follows:

```
id|created
3|2012-04-14 23:23:19
4|2012-04-14 23:04:31
5|2012-04-14 23:19:21
```

For 04/14/2012 this would make up to three hits. Thanks in advance, SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following query will group by a single date and give the count for a date:

```
SELECT count(id), DATE(created) FROM a_table GROUP BY DATE(a_table.created);
```

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. Which of these queries is likely to be faster? Vikram's looks a bit simpler to me.

Comment: Well then, I accept this as the answer, but +1 for Benjamin as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  String
FROM    TableName
WHERE   CURTIME() BETWEEN lowerlimit AND upperlimit
        OR CURTIME() BETWEEN SUBTIME(upperlimit, '24:00:00') AND lowerlimit
        OR SUBTIME(CURTIME(), '24:00:00') BETWEEN SUBTIME(upperlimit, '24:00:00') AND lowerlimit
```

See [S/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758095/mysql-select-where-time-now-between-tablevalue-and-tablevalue)